# How to send email to user after X days without login and repeat every week?

Tags: wordpress, email, repeat

How to send email to user after X days without login and repeat every week in Wordpress?
I don't know how to send emails every week after the first email.

Answer (score 1):

you have check email automatation, in this page you can get more information about the wordpress plugins:
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/tags/email-automation/

I suggest Mailchimp.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to use plugin to solve this problem. Can you help me?

Comment: Wordpress doesn´t have email automation, you have to use a application as Mailchimp, for example.